# Only allow specific user(s) access to a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Say I have a folder `/var/some_folder` and I have two users `user1` and `user2`.
How do I allow only `user1` to access that folder? If I make it read-only can't `user2` see it as well?

Note, `user1` should have read/write acces to the folder

I'm running CentOS 8

Comment: Type: `man chmod`

Comment: Thanks - `chmod 700 /var/some_folder` did the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can use linux groups:

- Create a new group: `groupadd newgroup`
- Change user and group of the file: `chown root:newgroup secretfile`.
- Change permissions of the file: `chmod 770 secretfile`. Which means only the owner (root) and users belonging to group newgroup can read, write, and execute secretfile.
- Add a user to the group newgroup: `usermod -a -G newgroup user1`. You can also add additional users as well if you need.